# Some FTP updates don't take effect, some do

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I'm wondering if anyone can help me, I'm running WP and I'm uploading and replacing files and SOME of the changes are there...

Then when I Inspect Element it's showing the OLD CSS. How is this happening? It's like it's caching my styles on the server for some reason?

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# Begin default subdomain redirect #
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^deadlineday.co
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.deadlineday.co/$1 [R=permanent,L]


# End default subdomain redirect #

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Shift+refresh? Also, check your source to be sure it's updating. Caching could be browser-side

Comment: I have cleared cache, viewed on other browsers... I think it's something to do with the server. Surely strange that it's showing old styles upon inspection?

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me a couple of times. In my case, the source files have path from "cdn", so we usually purge cdn cache for changes to be reflected on the server.

Is your case similar?